# Flutter app crashes on launch on Android

Tags: android, flutter

I've been testing my first Flutter app on iOS and its going well.  Now I run it for the first time in an Android simulator and I get this error.

```
07-18 11:42:10.757 4264-4264/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.akamojo.liga, PID: 4264
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.akamojo.liga.liga: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.akamojo.liga.liga" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.akamojo.liga-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.akamojo.liga-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.akamojo.liga-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It looks suspicious to me that is says it is looking for the class "com.akamojo.liga.liga".  Is it correct?  My applicationId is "com.akamojo.liga".  Is the Flutter framework creating a starting class called "liga"?

Here is build.gradle.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.akamojo.liga"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.akamojo.liga">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="liga"
        android:label="liga"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: im unsure how flutter works.... but check the main activity class name. what does it say at the first line? another thing is to check the manifest. see if for some reason it added an extra liga for the main activity

Comment: I added the AndroidManifest.xml file to the question.

Comment: this could be why. android:name="liga" add a . before it and report back.... so android:name=".liga"... before you do that. Do you have a class called liga? So my Android apps, I have an application class that gets called BEFORE mainactivity gets called.

Comment: I do not have a class called liga.  I figure this is something the Flutter framework is creating.  I added the period, but it didn't fix anything nor did it change the error.  So I een changed the name attribute to "liiiiiga" and it still did not change the error message.

Comment: Have you ever rename the package/project name ??

Comment: Yes I renamed it and then renamed it back.  Did I mess something up?  What can I fix?

Comment: have you tried setting "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" in the "android:name" in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes that fixed it.  Thanks.  If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Guys replace the package name with same inside app>src>main>kotlin>activity.kt

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your `mainActivity.kt` file

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); //Added line
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
}
```

Comment: This is no longer working. Is there another working solution?

Answer (score 0):

My app was working but after Dart plugin update I started to get this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo com.package.name.MainActivity
```

In my case it was because of incompatibility of Dart and Flutter plugin.
I ran flutter upgrade command and app starting working normal again.

So make sure to keep both Dart and Flutter plugins updated.

Answer (score 0):

First,
File>Project Structure> Select Project SDK Latest API Platform and go modules(dependencies) and select Latest API Platform, apply,OK.
Second,
in build-gradle => compileSdkVersion 28,targetSdkVersion 28  to change 30.
Third,
in build-gradle => GradleException to change FileNotFoundException

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience then I changed that package name of the project to android> app> src> main> MainActivity.kt or MainActivity.java and change your package com.example.name replace example with another.
The name which you have written in AndroidManiFest and app-level build file